# maraidb fill in missing hour, minute interval

Tags: mysql, mariadb, outer-join

I have a MariaDB table with the following schema:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| date              | date                | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| HE                | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| minute            | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| price             | float               | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The table contains prices on five minute intervals (hours 1-24 and minutes 0-55). Intervals without prices have no rows. I'm trying to write a query to fill in missing intervals with values of zero, without simply writing rows with that information in it.

I tried using a subquery with all 24 hours and 5 minute intervals and joining it to the he and minute columns without success.

The code I've tried below. The subquery correctly returns hours 1-24 and 5 minute intervals 0-55, but the final result only includes rows populated in the price table instead of the full time series. I was thinking right join should do it, but I also tried inner join, left join, and join without success.

```
select B.id, B.date, A.he, A.minute, B.price 
from price B 
right join (select distinct he, minute from price where id = 4093739409 and minute % 5 = 0 order by he,minute) as A 
on B.he = A.he and B.minute = A.minute 
where B.date = '2019-04-18' and B.id = 4093739409;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outer joining with list of hours and minutes ***from the data***, build a list of ***all hour-minute combinations*** and outer join:

```
SELECT x1.he, x2.minute, price.*
FROM (
    SELECT 01 AS he UNION ALL
    SELECT 02 UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 24
) AS x1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 00 AS minute UNION ALL
    SELECT 05 UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 55
) AS x2
LEFT JOIN price ON x1.he = price.he AND x2.minute = price.minute AND price.date = '2019-04-18' AND price.id = 4093739409
ORDER BY x1.he, x2.minute
```

In MariaDB you might be able to use row value constructor i.e. `(VALUES (01), (02), ..., (24)) AS x1(he)`.

Comment: Thanks Salman! This is pretty close, but results in NULL values for the intervals that are being filled in. If I can get the IDs and dates to fill in there (and have it work for the case with more than one id) then this will be perfect!

Comment: (If I understand correctly) the whole `price.*` will be null if there is no match. You can use `COALESCE(price, 0)` but the date needs to be hard coded `COALESCE(date, 'date-from-where-clause')`. BTW, You can add another cross join for the date and change the ON clause to `AND x3.date = price.date`.

Comment: Using the [sequence storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/) the large `UNION ALL` construct can be reduced to: `... FROM seq_1_to_24 x1 cross join seq_0_to_55_step_5 x2 LEFT JOIN ...`